# Django - Sending email works in shell, but not on localhost - ConnectionRefusedError

Tags: python, django, email, localhost, connection-refused

I'm new to Django, but I have read on the order of 50 pages (mostly SO and Django documentation) and haven't found anything that quite works for my situation.

I'm merely trying to send an email via the send_mail function in Django; although I'm hoping to get this working through SMTP on Gmail, right now it doesn't even work via localhost.  When I run my test_email.py file where I'm testing this send_mail function, I get the following error:

**ConnectionRefusedError**: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

When I run this same send_mail call in the shell (via python manage.py shell), it's completely fine and displays the email just as I would expect.  It's only once I try to run it in Django that the error pops up.  Note that I get the above error no matter which permutation of the following 2 sets of settings I put in my **settings.py** file:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

I've also played around with the following in my settings.py file, and various mixes of these settings with the previous set (though I guess I'm getting ahead of myself seeing how localhost isn't working):

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com' # Note I'm using my actual gmail address here in real life
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '****' # Note I'm using my actual gmail password here in real life

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myemail@gmail.com' # Note I'm using my actual gmail address here in real life
SERVER_EMAIL = 'myemail@gmail.com' # Note I'm using my actual gmail address here in real life
```

I'm running the following command in a CMD prompt off to the side when I try to run going the localhost route:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

Here's the **test_email.py** file I'm trying to run in Django, where I get the connection refused error:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail,EmailMessage

from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()

# Create your tests here.

# Email test #1: send email from my personal email to myself
send_mail(
    'Email Test #1',
    'Test if I can send email from my personal Gmail account to another email account via Django project.',
    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
    ['myemail@gmail.com'],
    fail_silently=False
    )
```

Any thoughts on why this isn't even working via localhost or suggestions on other things to try would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you connect to smtp.gmail.com:587 using telnet or similar? It is possible that you are behind a proxy/firewall that block some ports.

Comment: @Selcuk: I'm new to telnet too, but I entered "o smtp.gmail.com 587" it seems I can connect.

Comment: @Selcuk: I should note that I also tried to open a connection for telnet to localhost:1025 and the connection failed...

Answer (score 2):

I think there are some problem with `gmail smtp` service. Try using `smtp` service form [sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/). It is also free for basic usage. I too was facing the same issue earlier.

In **project settings.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'sendgridusername'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'sedgridpasseord'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'yourmail@site.com'
```

> still error

```
Try if `smtp` service is working on your server.
```

Comment: Thanks!  I set up an account on sendgrid and tried with the settings you suggested, but I'm still getting the same error.  Though, I was able to open up a connection to sendgrid via telnet (similar to Gmail - I can connect via telnet, but not via Django).

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration worked for me:

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey' # this is exactly the value 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'sendgrid-api-key' # this is your API key
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'your-email@example.com' # this is the sendgrid email
```

I used this configuration, and it worked properly, and I strongly suggest using environment variables to fill `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` and `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`:

```
import os # this should be at the top of the file

# ...

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD", "")
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = os.getenv("DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL", "")
```

In order to send an email, use the following code:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('This is the title of the email',
          'This is the message you want to send',
          settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
          [
              settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, # add more emails to this list of you want to
          ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your settings are in the `project settings.py` NOT `app settings.py` as follows

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

note the empty string for `EMAIL_HOST_USER` I think this is your mistake

Once you run your virtual python SMTP using

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

You will be able to send to your local smtp server with no problem.
[Source](https://gist.github.com/andreagrandi/7027319)

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable this option in your google account after you make sure that your mail and password is right.

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1

google blocks the access to insecure apps.

your code seems to be right!